# Calling a smart contract method using web3.js library

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am new to web3.js and I am trying to call a method from omesigo smart contract but I get a confusing error.
I have already read web3 doc and tried it.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "web3-learn",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.38"
  }
}
```

```
node version: 10.15.0
```

index.js related lines:

```
let contract = web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
contract.methods.name().call((err, res) => {console.log(res)});
```

```
/home/amin/Documents/projects/solidity-workshop/solidity-learn/src/web3-learn/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/nonIterableSpread.js:2
  throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance");
  ^

TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
    at _nonIterableSpread (/home/amin/Documents/projects/solidity-workshop/solidity-learn/src/web3-learn/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/nonIterableSpread.js:2:9)
    at _toConsumableArray (/home/amin/Documents/projects/solidity-workshop/solidity-learn/src/web3-learn/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:60)
    at CallContractMethod.set (/home/amin/Documents/projects/solidity-workshop/solidity-learn/src/web3-learn/node_modules/web3-core-method/dist/web3-core-method.cjs.js:405:34)
    at MethodsProxy.executeMethod (/home/amin/Documents/projects/solidity-workshop/solidity-learn/src/web3-learn/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/dist/web3-eth-contract.cjs.js:525:26)
    at Function.anonymousFunction.(anonymous function) [as call] (/home/amin/Documents/projects/solidity-workshop/solidity-learn/src/web3-learn/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/dist/web3-eth-contract.cjs.js:497:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amin/Documents/projects/solidity-workshop/solidity-learn/src/web3-learn/index.js:34:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

It should print Omisego token name. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by this line of code? Did you try debugging to see if it actually crashes there? And also based on the version of web3 you are using the `.call()` may return a promise instead of using a callback.

Comment: Yes, I tried every possible scenario. It crashes when I  try calling  `.call()` . It does not return any promises.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21734#issuecomment-433885436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing the same error, and solved it by upgrading the Web3 library to `"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.39"`

Looking deeper into the error, it seems related to the deep cloning of `contract.method arguments`. After a few hours of fruitless debugging, I stumbled upon the Web3 releases and saw that it was a featured release of `beta.39`. (released a day ago)

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue and the only difference from your approach is the version of web3 api, which for me is 1.0.0-beta.46. The resolution of the issue seems far fetched.